# Is it possible to get the click event without passing it to the handler?

Tags: javascript

I have something like that:

```
<div onclick="doSomething('foo', 'bar');"></div>
```

As you can see, the event isn't passed to the handler. Is it somehow possible to access it inside the handler anyway?

Comment: I don't understand what you want know... Don't you want to use the onclick attribute? is it?

Comment: Not in a cross-browser way. In IE and Chrome you can access `window.event`.

Comment: It's not something I would have wanted to do but a problem I was tasked to face :)

Comment: duplicated with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849370/get-the-event-object-in-an-event-handling-function-without-pass-the-event-object

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see, the event isn't passed to the handler. Is it somehow possible to access it inside the handler anyway?

No.

The best way to accomplish this is to add an id to your div, and set up the event handling from a script.

This should do what you're looking for

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

---

And then

```
function doSomething(evt, str1, str2) { ... }

document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick = function(e) {

    doSomething(e, 'foo', 'bar');

};
```

Just make sure the script tags that contain the above are *at the bottom* of you body tag, so the script doesn't run until the dom is created and ready.

Comment: Of course that's the way to go and it's the only one I use. But I would like to find out if there is a way to do it the way described in the question - i.e. without changing the inline call.

Comment: This is the preferred way, but you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you're right.  I actually don't know if it's possible to do it with the same code he has.  If you post an answer I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @Przemek: Without changing the inline call?  Pretty sure the answer is "no".

Comment: @AdamRackis: I don't have an answer. If that's because this can't be done, and if you add "no" to the beginning of _your_ answer, I'll be happy to upvote it ;)

Comment: Well - this is the right answer, so the only way for me is to accept it. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @AdamRackis: There you go ;)