# Javascript delete validation whether "Ok" or "Cancel"

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Hi guys i'm currently working on a delete validate function in javascript. Here is my code.

```
  function confirmDelete(){
var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
  if(agree == true){
    return true
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

The alert dialog box comes out but whenever i press "Cancel" button it still deletes the file in the table

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href=".base_url()."main/delete?id=$row->id>"."<i class='icon-trash' rel = 'tooltip' title = 'Delete' id = 'delete' onClick = 'confirmDelete();'></i></a>";
```

I'm using CodeIgniter by the way any help will much be appreciated! Thanks guys! :)

Comment: why don't you use `base_url('main/delete?id='.$row->id)` instead of concatenating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use return statement where you are calling javascript function. 
Like below:

```
<a href=".base_url()."main/delete?id=$row->id>"."<i class='icon-trash' rel = 'tooltip'   title = 'Delete' id = 'delete' onClick = 'return confirmDelete();'></i></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Because the on click should be in the `<a>`, not the `<i>`. Also,</strike> your function could be simplified, considering `confirm` returns `true` or `false`:

```
function confirmDelete(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
}
```

Comment: It still does the same :(

Comment: Could you show the whole PHP line from the original code? Or just the HTML output? You posted something in between, which is hard to read.

Comment: public function delete(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $delete_row = array("id" => "$id");
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->delete_user($delete_row);  
    $this->view_emp();
}

Here is my delete function in my controller do you think I can put the validation in my controller?

Comment: @thisshit No, I mean the same you posted in the question, but complete, with echo, the outer quotes, etc. your quotes look suspect.

Comment: @thisshit Nevermind, JSHunjan is right, I missed that. The tip about simplifying your function stands, though.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts anyway sir! Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it directly inside your tag:

```
   <a href=".base_url()."main/delete?id=$row->id>"  OnClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this book?');"> Delete </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `event.preventDefault()`, if returning false on its own is not preventing the browser action.

You will need to get a reference to event or `window.event`.. which is somewhat browser-specific. jQuery or similar can help with this.

```
onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this book?')) event.preventDefault();"
```

(Though, with the above example, we're not returning 'false' any more -- ideally, we'd put the code in a method, and both return false *and* prevent default if the confirmation is negative.)

To test if it works, most simply:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault();"
```

See also:

- [jQuery: How to get the event object in an event handler function without passing it as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849370/get-the-event-object-in-an-event-handling-function-without-pass-the-event-object)
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html
- [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

The difference between returning 'false' and `e.preventDefault() will prevent the default event from occuring,`e.stopPropagation()` prevents it from bubbling up/ outwards & outer defaults occurring, but return 'false' does not stop it from bubbling.

So perhaps it would be better to put the `onclick` handler on the  link, which is performing the default action?