# JavaScript uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the image wherever the mouse is clicked. But getting this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: evt is not defined onmousedown`

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image move</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pos.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="display(evt)">
<img id="myimage" height=300 width=300 src="pos.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px"; alt="mypos" />
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function display(evt)
{
    var dom = document.getElementById("myimage");
    dom.style.top = evt.clientY+"px";
    dom.style.left = evt.clientX+"px";
}
```

Do I have to write `event` explicitly? What's the problem?

Comment: I think that brackets are reserved for defining functions and other things. I don't think you can use brackets in the name of a function, it'll confuse JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `onmousedown="display(event);"`. The active event is `event`, not `evt`.

When an event such as `onmousedown` occurs, the piece of JavaScript associated with it gets executed in a scope that defines the `event` object. *Some* browsers make it also available globally as `window.event`, [as elaborated by this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849370/get-the-event-object-in-an-event-handling-function-without-pass-the-event-object), meaning you wouldn't have to explicitly pass it to the `display` function.

Comment: Yes, it does solve the problem. Can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: @Robin: when you use an `on*` HTML attribute, the browser generates a function of the form `function(event) { /* attribute content */ }` . Therefore in order to refer to the event object, you have to use `event`. You used `evt`, but it's not defined anywhere, neither implicitly nor explicitly.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, now it makes more sense.