# Pass event object in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometime you see that we need `event` object in javascript.
Here is some code how can we pass `event`.

```
 function test(e){
  console.log(e); 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("you are not going to redirect");
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="www.google.com" onclick="test(event)">GOOGLE</a>
```

Just pass the `event` in function argument if you want to pass event in function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the event object in an event handling function without pass the event object as parameters? (with jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849370/get-the-event-object-in-an-event-handling-function-without-pass-the-event-object)

Comment: I want to use `e.preventDefault()` you can see the update question

Comment: your code semms correct, the prooblem is that your code does not show a code that goes allong with your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` does not pass an event object to its callback.  And, even if you do find some way to get access to an event object in `setTimeout()`, it will be too late at that point to call `e.preventDefault()` because the default action will have already occurred.

So, your current approach to solving whatever problem you're trying to solve will not work.  If you back up a few steps and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, we could probably help you find a different way to solve it.

FYI, this type of question is known as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you describe a problem with your solution rather than the actual real problem you're trying to solve.  An XY question vastly limits how we can help you.