# jQuery e.target e is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have multiple `div` with the same class `class="galao"` and all of them have a `p` tag with the same class `class="nomeGalao"` as well. I'm trying to use a `e.target` in order to trigger a `mouseover` event and change the class of that especific `p` tag (div's child).

Here is my code

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
  }
}, ".galao");
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" class="galao">
  <div class="informacoesGalao">
    <div class="tabelaInformacoes infoGalao" style="float:right; text-align:right">
      <p class="invisible nomeGalao">Produto A</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="" class="galao">
  <div class="informacoesGalao">
    <div class="tabelaInformacoes infoGalao" style="float:right; text-align:right">
      <p class="invisible nomeGalao">Produto B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm getting a undefined `e`, even when I'e already used a `e.target` in another function.

Comment: You need to define elements context in functions argument `mouseenter: function (e) {`  and  `mouseleave: function (e) {`

Comment: you have to receive the event object in your event handler functions

Comment: `e` is an argument for your functions as your code is now, it's perfectly correct that it is undefined

Comment: [get the event object in an event handling function without pass the event object as parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5849370/3543808) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace what you have with this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on({
       mouseenter: function (e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
          $(target).children().removeClass('invisible');
    },
       mouseleave: function (e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
          $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
       }
    }, ".galao");
</script>
```

To explain, you need to pass 'e' as a parameter through your function, 'e' being the event. The links below may be helpful as well for your own personal reading:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Answer (score 3):

`e` is expected to be the parameter of your event handler function. Notice that you don't need to do the `e = e || window.event; var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`, that's exactly the kind of normalisation that [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handles for you. Just use [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) directly:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        $(e.target).children().removeClass('invisible');
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
        $(e.target).children().addClass('invisible');
    }
}, ".galao");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parameters to your function :

```
function(e){}
```

Comment: Ok that will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly following will help you

You are missing parameter  `e` in `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
  }
}, ".galao");
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" class="galao">
  <div class="informacoesGalao">
    <div class="tabelaInformacoes infoGalao" style="float:right; text-align:right">
      <p class="invisible nomeGalao">Produto A</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="" class="galao">
  <div class="informacoesGalao">
    <div class="tabelaInformacoes infoGalao" style="float:right; text-align:right">
      <p class="invisible nomeGalao">Produto B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on({
     mouseenter: function (e) {
      var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
      ....
  },
     mouseleave: function (e) {
       ....
   }
  }, ".galao");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parameter to your function:

```
$(".nomeGalao").on("mouseenter", function(e){
      e = e || window.event;
      var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
      $(target).children().removeClass('invisible');
});
```

It is not going to work since you have no e object inside of your function.
e stands for the event object, so please read the following:  https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/